# How to format two dictionaries based on common keys?

Tags: python, dictionary

Two dictionaries `d1` and `d2`, can contain `same keys with same values`, `same keys with different values` and `different keys`. Need to consider with similar keys in both d1 and d2. If value of such similar keys of d1 lesser than d2, then capture such `key:value` pair.
And also, another to capture having key:value of d1 without lesser value of common key in both d1 and d2. Similarly, without higher value of common key in both d1 and d2 for d2. Able to achieve this but I think I'm using many dictionaries to handle this. Any better way this can be implemented ? Any optimisation can be done ?

**Code:**

```
d1 = {"a": 5, "b": 6, "c": 7, "d": 8, "e": 9, "f": 2}
d2 = {"a": 6, "b": 4, "c": 8, "d": 5, "f": 2}

less_values_of_d1 = {}
without_lesser_values_of_a_key_of_d1 = {}
without_higher_values_of_a_key_of_d2 = {}
for i in d1:
   if i in d2:
      if d1[i] < d2[i]:
         less_values_of_d1[i] = d1[i]
      else:
         without_lesser_values_of_a_key_of_d1[i] = d1[i]
         without_higher_values_of_a_key_of_d2[i] = d2[i]
   else:
        without_lesser_values_of_a_key_of_d1[i] = d1[i]
        
print("d1:", d1)
print("d2:", d2)
print("less_values_of_d1:", less_values_of_d1)
print("without_lesser_values_of_a_key_of_d1:", without_lesser_values_of_a_key_of_d1)
print("without_higher_values_of_a_key_of_d2:", without_higher_values_of_a_key_of_d2)
```

**Output:**

```
d1: {'a': 5, 'b': 6, 'c': 7, 'd': 8, 'e': 9, 'f': 2}
d2: {'a': 6, 'b': 4, 'c': 8, 'd': 5, 'f': 2}
less_values_of_d1: {'a': 5, 'c': 7}
without_lesser_values_of_a_key_of_d1: {'b': 6, 'd': 8, 'e': 9, 'f': 2}
without_higher_values_of_a_key_of_d2: {'b': 4, 'd': 5, 'f': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do some dictionary comprehension. Here is one example.

```
less_values_of_d1 = {k:d1[k] for k in set(d1.keys()).
                                      intersection(set(d2.keys()))
                                      if d1[k]<d2[k]}
```